# como recebo dados de inputs que serão gerados dentro da estrutura de repetição?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
* ul li{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

</style>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><label for="input">didite o numero de contas</label></li>
        <li> <input type="number" id="input" placeholder=""></li>
        <li><button onclick="enviar()">Enviar</button></li>
    </ul>

</body>
<script>
    function enviar(){
        let txt = document.getElementById('input')
        let input = Number(txt.value)
        var tela = document.getElementById('visor')
       // document.write('ok')
      c = 1
      while(c <= input){
          //document.write('ok')
         document.write(`<br><label>${c}ª Conta</label><br><input type="number" id="conta${c}"<br>`)

          c++
      }
      document.write(`<br><button onclick="enviarContas()">Enviar</button>`)
    }

    function enviarContas(){

        con = 1 
        while(con <= input){

            //receber dados de input ${c}ªconta
        }    
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Como assim receber dados?

Comment: fiz uma estrutura de repetição que a pessoa digita o numero de contas que tem pra pagar ex: claro, tv, carro, casa [4] dai se cria 4 input number para receber os valores dessas [4]contas e no final poderia manipular os dados tanto somar como multiplicar etc...

Comment: esta ai @isaac :D espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom se eu entendi bem, você gostaria de gerar esses inputs de contas automaticamente como seu código ja está fazendo, e apartir disto você gostaria de pegar enviar os dados desses inputs.

Sendo assim desenvolvi esta solução simples:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
* ul li{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

</style>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><label for="input">didite o numero de contas</label></li>
        <li> <input type="number" id="input" placeholder=""></li>
        <li><button onclick="enviar()">Enviar</button></li>        
    </ul>
    
    <div id="valores">
      valores      
    </div>

</body>
<script>
    function enviar(){
        let txt = document.getElementById('input')
        let input = Number(txt.value)
        var tela = document.getElementById('visor')
       // document.write('ok')
      c = 1
      while(c <= input){
          //document.write('ok')
         document.write(`<br><label>${c}ª Conta</label><br><input type="number" id="conta${c}"<br>`)

          c++
      }
      document.write(`<br><button onclick="enviarContas()">Enviar</button>`)
    }
    let aux = 0;
    let soma = 0;
    function enviarContas(){
       const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="conta"]');  
       inputs.forEach(input => {
        console.log(input.value);
        if(!aux) document.write("<br/>valores: <br />");
        document.write(input.value  && `<p>${input.value}</p>`);
        soma += Number(input.value);
        aux++;
       });
       document.write(`<p>Total: ${soma}</p>`);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Dentro do foreach você consegue acessar todos os inputs gerados e assim fazer o que quiser com os dados

```
function enviarContas(){
       const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="conta"]');  
       inputs.forEach(input => {
        console.log(input.value);
       });
    }
```

Explicando um pouco melhor esse código final:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="conta"]')
```

`document.querySelectorAll` serve para dentro da sua dom voce selecionar mais de um elemento baseado nos valores que voce colocara dentro da função, no nosso caso:

```
('[id^="conta"]')
```

aonde `id` siginifica para ele pegar os elemento com o `id`, e `^` siginifica começando com. E `"conta"` seria o valor que o id deve começar.

Comment: quando aperto enviarContas() nao acontece nada poderia me mostrar um exemplo pegando e somando a quantidade de contas ?

Comment: veja no console.log() ele esta mostrando os dados colocados no seu input conta

Comment: no seu rodou ? no meu nao acontece nada

Comment: desculpe meu amigo consegui

Comment: muito grato de vdd com sua ajuda!

Comment: editei ela para voce visualizar melhor, caso seja isso mesmo, pode marcar minha resposta como certa e marcar como útil :)

Comment: só mais uma coisa amigo tu sabe como faço para dar a somas desses elementos?

Comment: como assim soma?

Comment: somar todos dados que recebi do input do looping

Comment: se vc quiser olhar o código que estou fazendo 
https://github.com/IsaacDSC/Contas---JS
mas só nao repara no style que ainda só estou testando

Comment: pronto alterei a resposta com a soma, por favor marque minha resposta como a resposta da pergunta, para fechar sua questão